# How to check if page reload is finished

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, reload

I have a button that the user clicks and it submits a form and page reloads upon submitting. I want to check whether the reloading of the page is finished. I tried using the one below 
but that gives the alert directly after the form is submitted even before the loading was finished.

```
if(window.performance.navigation.type == 0){
    alert('loaded');
}
```

How can I check if the loading is finished. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

*DOMContentLoaded and Load* are useful for that purpose ([link](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded))

> DOMContentLoaded – the browser fully loaded HTML, and the DOM tree is
>   built, but external resources like pictures  and stylesheets may
>   be not yet loaded.
>
> load – not only HTML is loaded, but also all the
>   external resources: images, styles etc.

Load should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is a common mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be more appropriate.

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    });

   //===================

   window.onload = function() { 
    // same as window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    alert('Page loaded');

    // image is loaded at this time
    alert(`Image size: ${img.offsetWidth}x${img.offsetHeight}`);
   };
```

As per your question, you want to check after the form submission. So When the form submits, window gets reloaded and entire doc reloads.

Also you can use the **document.readyState** to check the documents is loaded fully or not.

> The [document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) property can be used to check if the document
>   is ready. From MDN:
>
> Values The readyState of a document can be one of following:
>
> loading – The document is still loading. interactive – The document
>   has finished loading and the document has been parsed but
>   sub-resources such as images, stylesheets and frames are still
>   loading. complete – The document and all sub-resources have finished
>   loading. The state indicates that the load event is about to fire.

You can use the below code.

```
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    // Fully loaded!
    }
    else if(document.readyState === "interactive") {
         // DOM ready! Images, frames, and other subresources are still 
       downloading.
    }
    else {
       // Loading still in progress.
       // To wait for it to complete, add "DOMContentLoaded" or "load" 
         listeners.

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        // DOM ready! Images, frames, and other subresources are still 
        downloading.
    });

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        // Fully loaded!
    });
 }
```

Comment: How can I bind this to a button so that it checks for loading after button click?

Answer (score 2):

you could make use of `onreadystatechange` event and check the `document readyState`. If the `readyState` has value `complete` then show the alert.

> The readystatechange event is fired when the readyState attribute of a document has changed

Or just load the javascript code at the end of the body.

Example:

```
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
     alert('loaded');
  }
};
```

Comment: This one works nicely but the only problem is, it also gives alert when I refresh or first open the page. How can I bind this to a button so that it works after I click the button.

Comment: You could add event listener for the button inside the if check .

Comment: Instead of alert just add event listener.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window.onload:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  alert("loaded");
};
```

```html
<button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event